# Is Java 8 API internal implementation of collections using the new Java Stream API?

Tags: multithreading, collections, jvm, java-8, java-stream

[Java 8 Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/stream/package-summary.html) allows using <strike>implicit</strike> parallelization when executing code. I can't find anywhere whether the internal implementation of collections (such as HashSet and HashMap) in Java 8 is using these. The point is that if it were, then the single-threaded code that uses these collections would execute (internally) multi-threaded, thus potentially improving the performance significantly.

We have a single-threaded program and when it is executed in JVM, then JVM is using 100% (or about that much) of 8 cores. And we would like to know why and for what purpose and whether one could possibly control this. The amount of effective CPU time spent for the computation might be lower in case of parallel execution in JVM. Thus we might do better if A) we make use of 8 cores by just running 8 single-threaded programs (also executed as single-threaded) at the same time than B) giving 8 cores to a single program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No existing functionality will suddenly turn from sequential execution to parallel execution for at least following reasons:

- functions or call-backs passed to routines might not be prepared to be called concurrently
- applications carefully performing load balancing between CPU cores will find themself suddenly doing a bad job because code assumed to run on one core only utilizes more cores than expected
- even if the application won’t utilize the CPU cores otherwise, it’s not possible for a library to predict whether the application’s problem will actually benefit from parallel processing, i.e. given the number of elements to process and the actual cost of processing a single element

You might notice the new APIs allowing parallel processing explicitly, like the [`Arrays` utility class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Arrays.html) now offering `parallelSort` in addition to `sort`, etc.

Further note that the Stream API does not allow *implicit* parallelization either, you have to request a parallel stream *explicitly*, using `Collection.parallelStream()` or `Stream.parallel()` or using `true` for the `parallel` parameter of the factory methods in `StreamSupport`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, you have a point about the explicit vs. implicit here. What I meant was that just rpleacing sort() for parallelSort() does the parallelization ("implicitly") without the programmer having to do any parallelization themselves. In this sense, it is implicit :-). About your three points: 1) clear - but the scenario I have in mind is about situation when no callbacks are provided; 2) and 3) that's what I mean, but did Java developers really think about that? The fact, the process runs about 700% cpu. Is that all garbage collection being done in parallel?

Comment: And if it is only garbage collection, does it not violate 2) and 3) ? The code we run for sure has no "parallel" and no threads whatsoever. I can't paste it here as it is a student homework solution, but the imports should tell: 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

Comment: Parallel GC can be configured via command line, so it doesn’t come out of a sudden (and it’s not a new feature of Java 8). Further, GC threads are designed to go out of the way, if there’s heavy computation going on (unless there’s real pressure on memory). So it’s hard to believe that that’s the sole reason for the CPU utilization, but you can easily verify with `-XX:+UseSerialGC` whether it is…

Comment: Great hint, thanks. We applied the switch and yes, now the utilization dropped to 100%. So it was only GC. However, the program now crashed on lack of heap space. If run without the switch, it runs for many minutes and never crashes on heap space. It seems that the switch not only instructs to use single thread for GC, but also changes the policy. However, the output from htop suggests that the GC threads are regular system threads running on the same priority as the main program thread, i.e. if we run another parallel program, it will compete with the GC threads equally, which is not so nice.

Comment: Using the -XX:ParallelGCThreads=#, where # is the number of GC threads (as nicely explained here: http://developer.amd.com/4-easy-ways-to-do-java-garbage-collection-tuning/ ) leads to roughly 100% CPU utilization (single core) and no lack of heap space error.